# Are java.lang.Class objects ever garbage collected?

Tags: java, object, reference, garbage-collection

My question is if objects of type `java.lang.Class` ever gets garbage collected. Example:

```
WeakReference<Class<Object>> ref = new WeakReference<>(Object.class);
assertEquals(ref.get(),null);
```

Is this possible to ever assert to true? Can the reference to a java.lang.Class object ever get invalid?

Comment: It's possible, but certainly not with `Object`.

Comment: Object is just an example could have used Foo. But they should be a static reference in the classloader as far as i know, so how can they ever get gc'ed?

Comment: There's no such thing as "the" classloader.  There can be more than one, and they can get GC'd themselves.

Comment: But you can get the objects in a static fashion ```Object.class``` wouldn't that mean that they have a static reference?

Comment: The ones that you get that way, sure.  Not all `Class` objects are obtained with `Foo.class`.  Look at the methods in `ClassLoader`, e.g. `defineClass`.

Comment: That seems to be the answer to my question. "You can't rely on a java.lang.Class instance to be static". I am building some raw pointer stuff and was hoping to store the class as it's instance pointer as an long. But since I can't rely on the validity of that "blind" pointer I will need to reconsider my approach. Louise Wasserman thanks a lot.

Comment: You can’t rely on the validity of any instance pointer. The garbage collector moves objects in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `java.lang.Class` is tied to the `class` it represents. The garbage collection of the `Class` instance implies unloading the class, which is possible, but only under certain circumstances. For a normal class or interface, it requires not only the `Class` object but also its defining `ClassLoader` instance to become unreachable, which in turn requires all classes of this particular class loader to be unreachable.

That’s addressed in the specification in [§12.7. Unloading of Classes and Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.7):

> An implementation of the Java programming language may *unload* classes.
>
> A class or interface may be unloaded if and only if its defining class loader may be reclaimed by the garbage collector as discussed in [§12.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6).
>
> Classes and interfaces loaded by the bootstrap loader may not be unloaded.

All [Built-in Class Loaders](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#builtinLoaders) will never become unreachable.

But there’s also the [`defineHiddenClass` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#defineHiddenClass(byte%5B%5D,boolean,java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup.ClassOption...)) which allows to define special, “hidden” classes which may get garbage collected even if their defining loader is reachable (unless the [`STRONG` option](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.ClassOption.html#STRONG) has been specified).